# Java Streams Map, Get Value - List<Integer> from Key (With filtering)

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

Assuming I'm writing a method that takes in `Map<String, List<Integer>>` as shown below, and a String `name` to filter. My return type is `Stream<Integer>` how do I convert from a `Stream<List<Integer>>` to `Stream<Integer>`?

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> person = Map.of(
    "John", List.of(54, 18),
    "Alex", List.of(28), "Tom",
    List.of(78, 42)
);
```

My current implementation returns a `Stream<List<Integer>>`. Realistically, I would iterate through the list to retrieve all Integers in the list.

Code implementation:

```
return table.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(map -> map.getKey().equals(name))
    .map(map -> map.getValue());
```

Comment: You could use `flatMap` instead of `map` but I'd rather use a simple `map.getOrDefault(name, Collections.emptyList()).stream()`. Streaming the entire map and filtering for a single entry kind of defeats the purpose of using a map.

Comment: simple use the getOrDefault  , ex.  map.getOrDefault(name, Collections.emptyList()).stream()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *@Thomas* has pointed out in the comments, iterating over the whole Map would be wasteful. And [solution he proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74285954/java-streams-map-get-value-listinteger-from-key-with-filtering#comment131149758_74285954) probably is the cleanest one:

```
map.getOrDefault(name, Collections.emptyList()).stream()
```

Alternatively, you can make use of [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) without performing redundant iteration through the whole map like that:

```
public static <K, V> Stream<V> getStreamByKey(Map<K, Collection<V>> map,
                                              K key) {

    return Stream.ofNullable(map.get(key))
        .flatMap(Collection::stream);
}
```

The same result can be achieved with Java 16 [`mapMulti()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
public static <K, V> Stream<V> getStreamByKey(Map<K, Collection<V>> map,
                                              K key) {
    
    return Stream.ofNullable(map.get(key))
        .mapMulti(Iterable::forEach);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out in comments, use `flatMap` instead of `map` in the last step to reduce the double nesting:

```
return table.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(map -> map.getKey().equals(name))
    .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream());
```